# How to simplify an expression with a radical sign nesting in a radical sign

Tags: functions

[image: Picture]

Is there a function can simplify an expression with a radical sign nesting in a radical sign in *Mathematica*? I use V9.

`RatDenmon` is a function that can rationalize the denominator.

Comment: What output are you looking for?  Which alternative/simpler form would you use for `Sqrt[5 + Sqrt[5]]`?

Comment: `RootReduce` will give you a polynomial which has this number as a root.  `ToRadicals` converts it back.

Comment: Please do not post images of your work, especially when the images display at a size that make them unreadable. Please post your actual _Mathematica_ code as text that can be copied and pasted in a _Mathematica_ notebook. Without such, no one will be able to reproduce your problem, nor will they be able to experiment with possible repairs.

Comment: Code [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15926/51) might be of use.