# Symbolic integral not computed

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I know that:

$$\int\limits_0^\infty \left(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}\,\right)\sin{x}\,\text{d}x = \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\,\frac{e-1}{e}$$

but

```
Integrate[(Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[Sqrt[1 + x^2] - 1]) Sin[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

yields the integral itself in output after a few seconds.

Is there a way to get the correct result or can MMA provide only an approximation?

---

I found a way to fool MMA, that is to expand the double radical:

```
Integrate[(Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[(-1 + I x)/2] - Sqrt[(-1 - I x)/2]) Sin[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

> ```
> ((-1 + E) Sqrt[\[Pi]/2])/(2 E)
> ```

Is there a command that does this automatically?

---

Deepening further, I noticed that by writing:

```
Plot[Sqrt[Sqrt[1 + x^2] - 1] - (Sqrt[(-1 + I x)/2] + Sqrt[(-1 - I x)/2]), {x, -10, 10}]
```

we get:

[image]

and this, if I am not mistaken, indicates that MMA does not have an algorithm that can establish its equivalence.

Comment: For the approximation, you could use [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html).

Comment: Ok I correct the comment. You can check with `NIntegrate` code: `Sqrt[Pi/2]/2*((E - 1)/E) - NIntegrate[(Sqrt[x] - Sqrt[Sqrt[1 + x^2] - 1])*Sin[x], {x, 0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 200]` almost zero.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk You can verify the solution like that, but you cannot *compute* it (plus, being *close* does not necessarily mean they're equal). The assumption here is that you don't know the solution $\frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\,\frac{e-1}{e}$ a priori.

Comment: The questions arise: isn't it art for art's sake? where is this integral applied?

Comment: Note sure if useful, but your integral can also be written as a sum: `-Cos[1] + Sqrt[Pi/2] FresnelC[Sqrt[2/Pi]] + Sum[((-1)^(1 + n) (-1 + n) Sqrt[2/Pi] Gamma[-(7/2) + 2 n] HypergeometricPFQ[{-(1/2) + n}, {3/2, 1/2 + n}, -(1/4)])/Gamma[2 n] - ((1/16 + I/16) I^n (-I + (-1)^n) (Gamma[5/4 - n/2] Gamma[-(1/2) + n] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{5/4 - n/2}, {3/2, 9/4 - n/2}, -(1/4)] + 4 Sqrt[Pi] Sec[n Pi] Sin[1/4 (Pi + 2 n Pi)]))/Gamma[1 + n], {n, 1, Infinity}]`.

Comment: Note: Mathematica can evaluate the asymptotic part of the integrand `Integrate[ Sin[x]/(2 Sqrt[x] ), {x, 0, Infinity} ](*Sqrt[\[Pi]/2]/2*)`

Comment: How you expand the double radical? Could you explain and update the question?

Comment: related?:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15920/how-do-i-simplify-expressions-with-square-roots/15926#15926  [Though there the nested roots are purely numeric -- they don't include a variable.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FWIW, Wolfram|Alpha can denest this radical:

```
radical = WolframAlpha[
  "Simplify[Sqrt[Sqrt[1 + x^2] - 1]]", 
  {{"Result", 1}, "ComputableData"}
][[1]]
```

[image]

```
Integrate[(Sqrt[x] - radical) Sin[x], {x, 0, ∞}]
```

> ```
> ((-1 + E) Sqrt[\[Pi]/2])/(2 E)
> ```

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, you can de-nest roots using the identity

$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} (-a+i b x)}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} (-a-i b x)}=\sqrt{\sqrt{a^2+b^2 x^2}-a}$$
from which it follows that
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^+}\sqrt{\sqrt{a^2+b^2 x^2}-a}\ \sin x\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \sqrt{b} \left(1-e^{-\frac{a}{b}}\right)
$$
as given by

```
Integrate[
          (Sqrt[b x] - Sqrt[(-a + I x b)/2] - Sqrt[(-a - I x b)/2]) Sin[x]
         , {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0
]
```

Your integral corresponds to $a=b=1$,

```
% /. {a -> 1, b -> 1}
(* 1/2 (1 - 1/E) Sqrt[Pi/2] *)
```

as expected.

Comment: In general, radical de-nesting is a non-trivial problem. You can find some more details on the wikipedia page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical.

Comment: Doesn't the OP already have the de-nesting in the question, and asks, "Is there a command that does this automatically?"

Answer (score 1):

1
      2
    
    (
    −
    a
    +
    i
    b
    x
    )
  
  +
  
    
      1
      2
    
    (
    −
    a
    −
    i
    b
    x
    )
  
  =
  
    
      
        a
        2
      
      +
      
        b
        2
      
      
        x
        2
      
    
    −
    a

It seems that Mathematica does not know this way of expanding the nested square root. For example, changing the integrate to something else will still result in the unevaluated form. I think this is a bug or something.

Comment: Yes is something, but not a bug.