# How to simplify (square) roots in expressions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

e.g. it doesn't notice

```
Sqrt[9 C^2 + 8 w^2 - 3 C Sqrt[9 C^2 + 16 w^2]] =
(-3 C +Sqrt[9*C^2 + 16*w^2])/Sqrt[2]
```

The only way I found so far was doing it myself via `ReplaceAll`.
E.g. `FullSimplify[expr,{w>0,C>0}]`, `ExpandAll`, `PowerExpand`, `Refine` with `Assumptions` didn't work out.

Comment: `Reduce[Sqrt[ 9 c^2 + 8 w^2 -  3 c Sqrt[9 c^2 + 16 w^2]] == (-3 c + Sqrt[9*c^2 + 16*w^2])/ Sqrt[2], Reals]` give `True`.

Comment: @kglr right, but i want it to find the simplification itself, not to check if its true. (it was edited to consfusig ==)

Answer (score 1):

You have found one of many expressions that Mathematica, by default, does not simplify. However, it is possible to construct your own simplification functions. Here is one function for your situation:

```
ClearAll[tran, doit];
tran[ex_, m_: +1] :=
   ex /. {Sqrt[u_ + (v_: 1) Sqrt[w_]] :> doit[u, v, w, m]};
doit[u_, v_, w_, m_: +1] := Module[{x, y, z},
   x = u/v // Factor;
   y = Sign[m] Sqrt[x^2 - w // Factor] // PowerExpand;
   x = x + y // Factor;
   z = 2 x/v // Simplify;
   Sign[m] (x + Sqrt[w])/Sqrt[z] // Simplify // PowerExpand];
```

A simple example of usage is

```
3 - Sqrt[2] == tran[Sqrt[11 - 6 Sqrt[2]]]
```

which returns `True`. In your case, the usage is

```
ex1 = Sqrt[9 C^2 + 8 w^2 - 3 C Sqrt[9 C^2 + 16 w^2]];
ex2 = (-3 C + Sqrt[9*C^2 + 16*w^2])/Sqrt[2];
ex2 == tran[ex1]
```

which returns `True` again, as it should. The purpose of the parameter `m` is that sometimes the negative of the square root should be taken in the `y = ...` line of the `doit[]` code.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/178302/4346), we can get the result from `WolframAlpha`. Though in this case we need to increase the `TimeConstraint` for ["scantimeout"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha.html#719914703) and post process the result with `Refine`.

```
generalres = WolframAlpha[
  "Simplify Sqrt[9 C^2 + 8 w^2 - 3 C Sqrt[9 C^2 + 16 w^2]]", 
  {{"Result", 1}, "Output"}, 
  TimeConstraint -> {30, 30}
]
```

> [image]

```
Refine[generalres, C > 0 && w > 0]
```

> ```
> (-3 C + Sqrt[9 C^2 + 16 w^2])/Sqrt[2]
> ```

---

Here's the general result in a less compact but more understandable form:

```
floorArgPiecewiseExpand[expr_] := Simplify[FixedPoint[iFloorArgPiecewiseExpand, expr]]

iFloorArgPiecewiseExpand[expr_] := 
  Module[{k, s, args, ks, newexpr},
    args = Union[Cases[expr, _Arg, {0, ∞}]];
    ks = k /@ Range[Length[args]];
    newexpr = expr /. {(-1)^g_Floor :> s (-1)^(g + 1)} /. Thread[args -> ks];
    PiecewiseExpand[newexpr, AllTrue[ks, -π < # <= π &]] /. {s -> -1} /. Thread[ks -> args]
  ]

floorArgPiecewiseExpand @@ generalres
```

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
expr = Sqrt[9 C^2 + 8 w^2 - 3 C Sqrt[9 C^2 + 16 w^2]];
```

Assuming `C` and `w` are real, let `z^2 == 9 C^2 + 16 w^2` then

```
expr2 = Assuming[z > 0 && z^2 >= 9 C^2,
   expr /. w^2 -> (z^2 - 9 C^2)/16 // Simplify] /.
  z -> Sqrt[9 C^2 + 16 w^2]

(* (-3 C + Sqrt[9 C^2 + 16 w^2])/Sqrt[2] *)
```

Verifying,

```
expr == expr2 // Simplify[#, Element[{C, w}, Reals]] &

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey somehow cant comment ur nice answers (reputation and guest acc things). So 1st: thank you all!
Now @SOMOS Thats kinda high level for me, rly dont understand what u did there but it worked for the particular eq. however if i try it e.g.

```
ex1 = Sqrt[9 C^2 + 8 w^2 + 3 C Sqrt[9 C^2 + 16 w^2]];
ex2 = (+3 C + Sqrt[9*C^2 + 16*w^2])/Sqrt[2];
```

it wont work again, what would i have to change?

here is one of my matrix elements, perhaps u have other ideas for simplification?

```
(-(-3 coplC Sqrt[
      8 w1^2 + 3 coplC (3 coplC + Sqrt[9 coplC^2 + 16 w1^2])] + 
     Sqrt[(9 coplC^2 + 16 w1^2) (8 w1^2 + 
        3 coplC (3 coplC + Sqrt[9 coplC^2 + 16 w1^2]))]) Sin[(
   t Sqrt[9 coplC^2 + 8 w1^2 - 3 coplC Sqrt[9 coplC^2 + 16 w1^2]])/(
   2 Sqrt[2])] - (3 coplC Sqrt[
     9 coplC^2 + 8 w1^2 - 3 coplC Sqrt[9 coplC^2 + 16 w1^2]] + 
    Sqrt[-(9 coplC^2 + 16 w1^2) (-8 w1^2 + 
       3 coplC (-3 coplC + Sqrt[9 coplC^2 + 16 w1^2]))]) Sin[(
   t Sqrt[8 w1^2 + 3 coplC (3 coplC + Sqrt[9 coplC^2 + 16 w1^2])])/(
   2 Sqrt[2])])/(4 w1 Sqrt[18 coplC^2 + 32 w1^2])
```

@Chip Hurst

couldnt get it working, it just outputs crazy Arg[] things for me :(

@Bob Hanlon

i think this might need too much user input per equation

Comment: Or is there a way to do automated substitutions in long equations? like that mathematica recognizes certain parts that reappear in my equations?

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8787