# Small error on symbolic eigenvalue of $2\times2$ matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic

I have some computation where I specifically define a 2x2 matrix to have a specific eigenvector v associated with an eigenvalue g, and a second eigenvalue l :

```
$Assumptions = r > 1 && g > 0 && r ∈ Reals && g ∈ Reals;
v = {r - Sqrt[-1 + r^2], 1};
Mat[l_, t_] := {{t, (g - t) (r - Sqrt[-1 + r^2])}, {(t - l)/(r - Sqrt[-1 + r^2]), g + l - t}};
Simplify[Mat[l, t].v]
```

The output of this is, as expected :

```
{g (r - Sqrt[-1 + r^2]), g}
```

Thus, given that the trace is  l+g and g is an eigenvalue, the problem should be solved. However, when I ask the eigenvalues of this, I get:

```
{1/2 (g + l - Sqrt[(g - l)^2 (-1 + 2 r (r - Sqrt[-1 + r^2]))]/(-r + Sqrt[-1 + r^2])), 
1/2 (g + l + Sqrt[-(g - l)^2 (1 + 2 r (-r + Sqrt[-1 + r^2]))]/(-r + Sqrt[-1 + r^2]))}
```

EDIT : 
As pointed out by Roman, this is a simple problem of Mathematica not being able to simplify the expression

```
Sqrt[ (-1 + 2 r (r - Sqrt[-1 + r^2]))]/(-r + Sqrt[-1 + r^2])
```

to -1 for r > 1. Still interested in knowing why it is so, but not a linear algebra issue.

Comment: A few days ago there was a similar [Mathematica question 199009](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/199009)  "How to simplify (square) roots in expressions?" involving `Sqrt[u+v*Sqrt[w]]`. The answers there may help you here.

Comment: Mathematica seems  to ignore the identity `(r - Sqrt[-1 + r^2]))]/(r + Sqrt[-1 + r^2])==1`

Answer (score 1):

just as extended comment:

The plot

```
Plot[Sqrt[(-1 + 2 r (r - Sqrt[-1 + r^2]))]/(-r +Sqrt[-1 + r^2]), {r, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

makes no problems (MMA v11.0.1)!
Please clarify your question

Comment: The problem is that per assumptions we have $r>1$ but Mathematica refuses to simplify this expression to $-1$.

Comment: I used much larger r (e.g. in [1, 500]). It is a numerical approximation issue, not surprising and just a symptom of not having simplified to -1.

Comment: The plot is made without assumptions, MMA seems to have no problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Surd (which gives the real-valued square root) instead of Sqrt then you get the desired simplification:

```
v = {r - Surd[-1 + r^2, 2], 1};
Mat[l_, t_] := {{t, (g - t) (r - Surd[-1 + r^2, 2])}, {(t - l)/(r - 
               Surd[-1 + r^2, 2]), g + l - t}};

Eigenvalues[Mat[l, t]]
{g, l}
```