# How to use `TransformationFunctions` to simplify this expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I see this interesting question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15920/how-do-i-simplify-expressions-with-square-roots).

But I want to simplify it with the help of `Simplify` function (Maybe the `TransformationFunctions` and `ComplexityFunction` options will be used) . How can I reduce the expression  $\sqrt{5-2 \sqrt{6}}$  to  $ \sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}$ ?

```
Simplify[Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]]]
```

I hope to use MMA's `Simplify` function to achieve this simplification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[5 - 2 Sqrt[6]], ComplexityFunction -> (Count[#, Sqrt[6], Infinity] &)]

(*  -Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]   *)
```

Note that it works with `FullSimplify` but not with `Simplify`. I do not know the reason.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you use  `TransformationFunctions`  function to achieve this?